# Parse getDataInBackgroundWithBlock not fetching in order

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am fetching a string, NSDate and a PFFile from my Parse class to populate the collection view cells

All the cells load with image, date, info correctly. The info and date are ordered correctly (by ascending date). But every now and then when I build some of the images will be in a different cell. Im really scratching my head with this. Im guessing it has something to do with how I'm calling mixPhoto.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({

I did try and use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Still no luck... Heres my code, anyone got any ideas?

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!


var mixPhotoArray : Array<UIImage> = []
var mixInfoArray: Array <String> = []
var mixDateArray: Array <NSDate> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView1.delegate = self;
    collectionView1.dataSource = self;

    self.queryParseMethod()
    self.getImageData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func getImageData() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "musicMixes")
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    for object in objects {


    let mixPhoto = object["mixPhoto"] as PFFile

        mixPhoto.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    //image object implementation
                    self.mixPhotoArray.append(image!)
                    println(self.mixPhotoArray[0])
                    self.collectionView1.reloadData()

                }
            }
            else {
                println("error!!")
            }

        })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end

        }



    }//for - end

}

    func queryParseMethod() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "musicMixes")
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {


    let mixPhoto = object["mixPhoto"] as PFFile




        let mixInfo = object["info"] as String
        let dateForText = object["date"] as NSDate


        //self.collectionView1.reloadData()

            self.mixDateArray.append(dateForText)
            self.mixInfoArray.append(mixInfo)
            self.collectionView1.reloadData()


                }//for - end
        }
        }
} // end of queryParseMethod


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()




        }



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
     println("I have \(mixPhotoArray.count) Images")
    return mixInfoArray.count


}

  //func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:StreamCollectionViewCell = collectionView1.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as StreamCollectionViewCell

   cell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]
    cell.infoLabel.text = mixInfoArray[indexPath.item]

    // NSDate array into cell
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
   cell.mixDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(mixDateArray[indexPath.item])






     return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Wain said, I believe the main issue is that since your images are downloading at different speeds, they're not necessarily being appended to your array in order. Instead of recommending that you use a dictionary though, here's what I would recommend to circumvent that problem while still using an array:

```
// Declare your mixPhotoArray such that it can store optionals
var mixPhotoArray : Array<UIImage?> = []

func getImageData() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "musicMixes")
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        // Initialize your array to contain all nil objects as
        // placeholders for your images
        self.mixPhotoArray = [UIImage?](count: objects.count, repeatedValue: nil)
        for i in 0...objects.count - 1 {

            let object: AnyObject = objects[i]
            let mixPhoto = object["mixPhoto"] as PFFile

            mixPhoto.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        // Replace the image with its nil placeholder
                        // and do so using the loop's current index
                        self.mixPhotoArray[i] = image
                        println(self.mixPhotoArray[i])
                        self.collectionView1.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("error!!")
                }

            })

        }

    }

}
```

Then within `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you can set the image conditionally so that it only appears once its ready:

```
if mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item] != nil {
    cell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works in order all the time! I've run it a few times, but sometimes It crashes. I get a error at

if let image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item] {
    cell.mixImage.image = image
}

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why do you think sometimes this isn't being executed properly?

Comment: Also on occasion 1/2 of the cells will have no picture.. So it fails loading some. Any ideas what is causing this un reliability he

Comment: @MattPorter First off, I just realized I'd removed self.collectionView1.reloadData() for my own testing purposes so make sure you have that within your block so that the table reloads after each image is loaded. Secondly, I'm not sure why `if let` wasn't working for you in this case, but I've simplified that line of code with a straight-forward if statement, so try that instead.

Comment: Yep! I think the reload data sorted it out. Im guessing some of the images wasn't getting updated. Adding that into the block makes sense I shouldn't of missed that! My mad. Thanks Lyndesy you have very helpful!

Comment: Meh still running into 

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the 

if mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item] != nil {
    cell.imageView!.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]
} else {
println("error!")
}

I even added a else statement but it don't seem to want to jump to that when it find nil! Why is this not that reliable hhhmmmm

Comment: @MattPorter Possibly caused by another edit I made to your code while debugging... Change `cell.imageView!.image =` back to `cell.mixImage.image = `

Comment: I already changed that! Im 99% sure its due to the cell configuration happening before all the array has been downloaded. I spent a while looking though the debugger. I run into this error before the getImageData() is complete. What can I do to make this this run and completes before that code gets executed? Its already in the viewDidLoad and on the main thread. Can I add something to this if statement to do this.

Comment: @MattPorter As long as mixPhotoArray allows for optional values, you won't encounter that error on the `if` line. (I've tested it myself...and mixPhotoArray can even hold all nil values without triggering that error.) Which line shows the error? The if line or the line within your block? Because if the line within your block is causing the error, I suspect `mixImage` or `cell` may be nil.

Comment: I tested my theory with sleep(2) before assigning cell.mixImage.image = 
and it works every time but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this!

Comment: @MattPorter Was the error coming from the line within your block? And did you put sleep within your block? Because then that would actually prove that the error's occurring when the value is non-nil and that the issue isn't what you think it is...

Comment: The error is coming from here in the config cell
if mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item] != nil {
// I added sleep(2) here and it runs every time no fail
    cell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]
} 

I have a println on the end of my block... that never came in the console when I hit the error in the cell. So it clears up that I'm hitting this error before the block is completed. The sleep in the cell gives the block enough time to complete but there must be a cleaner option.. like a if statement for when this function is completed

Comment: @MattPorter I still don't think you're understanding the issue here... As an experiment, try removing the if block and simply replacing it with `cell.mixImage.image = UIImage()`. I suspect you'll encounter the same fatal error.

Comment: No error! The error comes from accessing the mixPhotoArray. Without sleeping before assigning it seems to execute this to soon and crash. I am saying this because I have some println's at the end of my getImageData function that don't appear in the console when it crashes. Which means that the function isn't completed. I am getting fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer on the if  mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item] != nil and in the debugger my mixPhotoArray has 0 values! Like I said with a sleep the problem disappears!

Comment: @MattPorter Wait... Now you're getting a "Cannot index empty buffer" error? This is completely different from a "unexpectedly found nil" error... Which is it?

Comment: I changed my array a little with var mixPhotoArray : Array<UIImage?>! = [] I get fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer. With var mixPhotoArray : Array<UIImage?>! I get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Bear in mind If I run this 10 times I will hit these errors about once or twice.. Which one should I keep the array at? Any idea's what is causing these errors? Thanks for sticking with this been scratching my head all day with this!

Comment: @MattPorter I think I know what's going on here: (1) Don't reload your collection view in the queryParseMethod() and (2) have numberOfItemsInSection `return mixPhotoArray.count` instead of `return mixInfoArray.count`. If `cellForItemAtIndexPath` executes after `self.queryParseMethod()` is called but before `self.getImageData()`, `mixPhotoArray` will be empty and since your numberOfItemsInSection returns `mixPhotoArray.count`, you'll be trying to access a nonexistent index of `mixPhotoArray`.

Comment: @MattPorter (con't) So, like I suspected, the issue isn't what you thought it was... The sleep only helped because it gave `self.getImageData()` enough time to execute its first query and thus pre-set `mixPhotoArray`'s elements to nil.

Comment: Nope still running into this every now and then! I won't bother you any more I feel bad! Thanks for your guidance! Ill keep hacking away at it. :(

Comment: @MattPorter No worries... Are you sure I've made all the changes I mentioned? If you'd like to upload your current code somewhere, I can take a look.

Comment: Yep! Going to go though it again.. I've just noticed after them few changes now the cannot index empty buffer is giving a error on cell.infoLabel.text = mixInfoArray[indexPath.item]. We seem to be ok with the mixPhotoArray now! haha. So what the f is causing this do you think? Ill take the last few words from you and if I can get to the bottom myself I will upload it and send you a link (Your amazing)

Comment: @MattPorter Yeah, I know the problem... It's basically what I just wrote, but now happening in reverse. Since self.queryParseMethod() and self.getImageData() aren't completing their async at the same exact time, sometimes `mixPhotoArray` is empty while `mixInfoArray` is full and vice versa. And since `numberOfItemsInSection` currently relies solely on the count of one of these arrays, there's a chance that one may be empty during the call to reload the data.

Comment: @MattPorter So here's what I recommend... (1) re-add the line reloading the data in `queryParseMethod()` (just in case it takes longer than `getImageData()` to execute) and (2) only reload the data when both array counts are equal, or add conditionals within `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to check that the arrays are greater than the index you're trying to access, or set `numberOfItemsInSection` to return whichever of  `mixPhotoArray` and `mixInfoArray` is smaller, etc. (there are plenty of ways you can go about this.)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your data in 2 arrays, `mixPhotoArray` and `mixInfoArray`, but you can't guarantee that they will both be in the same order. Images are different sizes so they will download at different speeds. You also shouldn't really be trying to download more than 4 at once so your current scheme isn't great.

Instead, you should have an array of dictionaries or custom classes which hold all of the details and which, when each image is downloaded, is updated with that image.

Obviously this means that you need to know which one is associated with the image you've just downloaded so you need to capture this dictionary / instance in the block so you can update it.

You could do it in 2 arrays as you are, so long as you capture an index where the image should be an insert the image to the array in the correct place.