# Parse File Query and Swift 1.2 Error - getDataInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to query images from Parse and I continue to run into `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value`. I'm not sure if this has to do with the recent update to Swift and Xcode, so maybe it's on the Parse end or it could certainly be user error.

The only things `getDataInBackGroundWithBlock` will accept are `NSData?` and `NSError?` as optionals. If I try unwrapping them or using other types it won't compile.

The `PFQuery` returns data as expected. It's only when trying to switch from `PFFile` to `NSData` in the `getDataInBackGroundWithBlock` call that the issue comes up.

The framework is hooked up and running. I've tested it quite a bit.

Here is the call stack: [image]

I've been working on this for over 12 hours straight now. I have looked all over the place and have tried many different things. I don't know anyone who works with Swift or Xcode, your help would go miles and miles.

Here are other threads I have tried to no avail, one is my own:

[Unresolvable error with Parse "Get Data In Background With Block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595084/unresolvable-error-with-parse-get-data-in-background-with-block/29595211?noredirect=1#comment47339146_29595211)

[Parse and Swift 1.2 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435355/parse-and-swift-1-2-issue)

[Parse getDataInBackgroundWithBlock not fetching in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648188/parse-getdatainbackgroundwithblock-not-fetching-in-order)

[Swift Image retrieving from Parse sdk - getting crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764618/swift-image-retrieving-from-parse-sdk-getting-crashed)

Also Parse docs:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS  (their example was my starting point today)

```
var photoArray: Array<UIImage> = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    callPFObjectQuery()

    let testObject = PFObject(className: "QuestionMaster") //testobject
    testObject["foo"] = "bar" //testobject
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Object has been saved.")

    }
} 

func callPFObjectQuery() {

    var finalObjects: [PFObject] = []
    var nsdataObjects: NSData?

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionMaster")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {

            let imageFiles = object["questionImage"] as! PFFile!

//error line     imageFiles.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                            self.photoArray.append(image!)
                            println(self.photoArray[0])

                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Update, November 12, 2015 - Swift 1.2:** It's been quite a few months since I've posted this and since it has over 1k views and an answer with no upvotes I felt it best to go back over it and make sure what I selected was indeed correct. I haven't gone through and tested it again but having become very, very familiar(6-8k lines) with the Parse SDK and Swift I feel comfortable with the answer I provided. Uttam Sinha was very close but unwrapping instead of optionals on completion handler in `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` won't work. They must be optionals and then unwrapped in the block. Ingouackaz missed the for-loop entirely, but his `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` call is correct.

My first attempt was sloppy at best, I was probably frustrated. For those of you that are just beginning, the query right before the data query will complete with an array of `PFObject`'s. Therefore you need to loop through that array, calling `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` on each item.

Instead of `object["questionImage"]` I would probably go with `object.valueForKey("questionImage")` just to make it more explicit. I would also store the key string `"questionImage"` as a constant in a file of keys so there would be no need to worry about typos.

I'm not sure about PDF files and Parse. I haven't attempted since that situation. But now I am curious because that would once again make my job easier if possible. I will update once I try again.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show it, what is the value of `imageFiles`?

Comment: @Paulw11 The value of `imageFiles` is a PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. However, this method will not work with vector images. It seems that convenient feature in storyboard is not accessible through code yet. At least not in this way.

You can note that the problem was simple white spacing in the `imageFiles.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` line. Had to subtract a space and add parentheses. Thanks to @user2770692 for pointing that out.

```
func queryImages() {

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionMaster")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {

            let imageFiles = object["questionImage"] as! PFFile

            println(imageFiles)

            imageFiles.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    println(image)
                }

            })

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work with Swift 1.2

```
file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    println(image)
                }

            })
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to work with this file in a couple of days so I'm just now returning to it. Sometimes I have to step away and clear my head.

This is very, very close. `image` is still returning `nil` but it's returning `nil` for  every file (the file count is correct) in the class which is progress being made.

I think the reason for `nil` being returned might be in using vector assets as opposed to PNGs. It seems programmatically it might not be possible to use vectors for UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works -

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil){

            self.getImageData(objects as [PFObject])

        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    })//findObjectsInBackgroundWithblock - end


func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {
    for object in objects {

        let thumbNail = object["questionImage"] as PFFile

        println(thumbNail)

        thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)                
                println(image)
            }

        })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end

    }//for - end
}
```

Comment: I can't compile if I unwrap(!) instead of making optional(?) `NSData` and `NSError`

Answer (score 0):

Remove "!" at the end in below line :

```
 let imageFiles = object["questionImage"] as! PFFile!
```

It should be like this:

```
 let imageFiles = object["questionImage"] as! PFFile
```